# Changed memory address using realloc in C

Tags: c, realloc

I do have a question about the Reallocation of memory in C, because I think this is causing a problem which I have for a week now, without finding it.
I am you have squared paper and your somebody filled a couple of squares with green colour. So now, I am trying to read the coordinates of the green squares (somebody puts them into the stdin) and then I would like to link them together by looking if they are neighboured together.
So in the Cell struct, all the Cells do have coordinates, pointers to potential neighbours and a counter of neighbours. And there is a function called setNeighbours which figures out if they are neighbours and fills the addresses into every object.
So my problem is about the reallocation method, because I know this is potentially moving the address block to somewhere else and in reason for that, sometimes (maybe 40% of the times) I am getting wrong results when printing out the results.

The code is below.
I know that the reallocation line is the reason, because if I do delete it and just put enough space into the malloc line so there is no need for realloc later, then everything works fine.
I guess there is one stupid moment where I am calling for an old address which has changed before, but I cannot see the it. Does one see it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct Square {
    long index;
    long x;
    long y;
    struct Square *Above;
    struct Square *Below;
    struct Square *Right;
    struct Square *Left;
    int count;
} SquareType;

SquareType *cellArr;
long countSquares = 0;
```

Example input:

```
1 3
2 3
3 3
2 2
2 1
3 2
```

Comment: Why not use `sscanf("%d %d")` in `proofString()`?

Comment: The loop that calls `setNeighbours()` should just be done once, after you have read all the coordinates, instead of after reading each line.

Comment: If you do that, all the reallocations will be done first, and you won't have any dangling pointers to the old addresses.

Comment: Use indexes (offsets into the array) instead of pointers.

Comment: Why are you using global variables? Bad habit to get into

Comment: The realloc looks OK to me. What looks wrong to me is your use of indices of cellArr. For example right below the alloc you do something with cellArr[countSquares] and then loop from 0...countSquares-1. Make up your mind.

Comment: Move `for(int i=0;i<countSquares;i++) {
            setNeighbours(&cellArr[i], &cellArr[countSquares]);
        }` to after the all the reading. ( and re-iterate for all `countSquares`.

Comment: @Barmar Note that `sscanf("%d %d")... ` needs to be `sscanf("%ld %ld" 
 ...` here.  Still your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50631899/changed-memory-address-using-realloc-in-c#comment88274070_50631899) is sound.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. @Barmar I am using a more complicated method because I tried to train a little bit about reading documents and interacting with string arrays. That’s the simple and odd reason I am not using your line, which would be even better. :)

Comment: Thanks to all the others, you are totally right with the call of setNeighbours. I puttet that to afterwards the while loop now and it‘s working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> So my problem is about the reallocation method, because I know this is
>   potentially moving the address block to somewhere else and in reason
>   for that, sometimes (maybe 40% of the times) I am getting wrong
>   results when printing out the results.

Indeed, `realloc()` does not always put the reallocated block at the same address as the original one.  If you reallocate the space containing your structures then you have to assume that any pointers to those structures obtained prior to the reallocation cease to be valid.  Your code does not seem to be making that assumption.

There are only a few viable solutions:

- Do not rely on pointers into the allocated space, other than the main one you maintain to the beginning of the space.  One way to achieve that would be to identify neighbors by their indexes instead of by pointers directly to them.  Or,
- Set up the pointers only after reading all the data, so that you can be sure all needed reallocations have already been performed.  Or,

  - Special case: recompute all the pointers whenever the data are reallocated to a different address.  Or,
- Avoid reallocating.  You can do that either by allocating sufficient space for everything up front (a pretty good option if you have or can get at least a reasonable upper bound on the amount you'll need), or by allocating each structure independently of the others.

Comment: Not his problem, and bad advice. The realloc() function is a perfectly good and useful function for developing dynamically-sized objects; "avoid it" is not useful advice. Also, he's using it correctly here, changing his pointer.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker After a re-allocation, the prior `setNeighbours()` need to be re-done or simply deferred until all the reading is done.  I'd say John is right here about the reallocation deficiency.  `realloc()` is OK, `setNeighbours()` placement is not.

Comment: Perhaps you read too quickly, @LeeDanielCrocker.  I never claimed that `realloc()` should not be used *in general*, but rather that reallocating a block of memory must be assumed to invalidate existing pointers into the original block.  One must either avoid that or deal with it, and I offered options for both.  Yes, the OP is changing his pointer to the block, but *the data within* include pointers to each other, and these are not being updated.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, thanks. If you're going to make a growing structure using realloc(), make sure that the things inside the growing (and possibly moving) part only point to things outside the growing part.